# Program to compress files using GPUs

Tags: compression, gpu

Are there any compression programs (e.g. gzip, 7zip, xz) that can use GPUs to accelerate compression?  I've been playing with a 5.7 GB qcow2 image of an OpenStack instance, and with xz using extra options I could get the file compressed to only 1.6 GB, but it took almost 2 hours to get that, compared to ~10 minutes when the compressed file size was 4.5 GB.  It got me to wondering if any programs use GPUs to speed it up.  I saw some discussion around NVIDIA's CUDA library ([Compression library using Nvidia's CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456829/compression-library-using-nvidias-cuda)).  Has anything been developed since then?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is new WinZip, uses GPU by OpenCL. You need to test to see if is good to you.